# Data Structure to Rank Objects

Tags: java, data-structures

I am looking for a data structure that will sort objects based on a given integer.  Like so:

```
Object    Score
Object1   86
Object2   85
Object3   85
```

Each object will be unique, but there can be duplicate scores.  Was trying to devise a way on how a Map object could do this, but can't figure it out.

Structure can either sort the objects during/after an insertion or when I implicitly call for a sort.

Is there a structure out there that does this already?  Or should I code it myself?

Comment: A [Min/Max Heap](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Structures/Min_and_Max_Heaps) should do what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting the objects in a `SortedSet` if you want unique values or a `List` if you want to see duplicates, along with a custom `Comparator` to sort them based on their "scores".

Providing your own Comparator will let you specify that the objects should be sorted on their `score` field and how.

The Comparator is also reusable and easy to swap in / out if you wanted to, say do a descending sort on the items.

So an example that might be:

```
  class ScoreComparator implements Comparator <ObjectHolder> {
    @Override
    public int compare(ObjectHolder o1, ObjectHolder o2) {
      return o1.getScore().compareTo(o2.getScore());
    }
  }

  class DescendingScoreComparator implements Comparator <ObjectHolder> {
    @Override
    public int compare(ObjectHolder o1, ObjectHolder o2) {
      return o2.getScore().compareTo(o1.getScore());
    }
  }


  class ObjectHolder {
    Object obj;
    Integer score;

    public ObjectHolder(Object o, Integer score) {
      this.obj = o;
      this.score = score;
    }

    public Object getObject() {
      return obj;
    }
    public Integer getScore() {
      return score;
    }
  }


  public void showExample() {
    SortedSet<ObjectHolder> sortedSet = new TreeSet<ObjectHolder>(new ScoreComparator());
    sortedSet.add(new ObjectHolder("addedFirst", 55));
    sortedSet.add(new ObjectHolder("addedSecond", 25));
    sortedSet.add(new ObjectHolder("addedThird", 75));
    sortedSet.add(new ObjectHolder("addedFourth", 25));
    sortedSet.add(new ObjectHolder("addedFifth", 95));

    // The resulting set will only have 4 items since sets don't allow duplicates
    for (ObjectHolder holder : sortedSet) {
      System.out.println(holder.getScore());
    }

    List<ObjectHolder> list = new LinkedList<ObjectHolder>();
    list.add(new ObjectHolder("addedFirst", 55));
    list.add(new ObjectHolder("addedSecond", 25));
    list.add(new ObjectHolder("addedThird", 75));
    list.add(new ObjectHolder("addedFourth", 25));
    list.add(new ObjectHolder("addedFifth", 95));

    Collections.sort(list, new ScoreComparator());

    // The resulting set will only have 5 items since lists allow duplicates
    System.out.println();
    for (ObjectHolder holder : list) {
      System.out.println(holder.getScore());
    }

    Collections.sort(list, new DescendingScoreComparator());

    System.out.println("\nWill print 5 items, but this time in descending order");
    for (ObjectHolder holder : list) {
      System.out.println(holder.getScore());
    }
  }
```

And here's the output of the above code:

> Will print 4 unique items since sets don't allow duplicates
>
> 25 55 75 95
>
> Will print 5 items since lists do allow duplicates
>
> 25 25 55 75 95
>
> Will print 5 items, but this time in descending order
>
> 95 75 55 25 25

Comment: An additional benefit is this approach doesn't require any 3rd party libraries.  It uses only pure Java.

Comment: FWIW I would keep the descending comparator more general, basically wrap an arbitrary comparator an on compare just invert (*-1) the wrapped comparators compare output. You obviously wouldn't call it descending comparator anymore but inverted

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use a map, use a `TreeMap` and supply your own `Comparator`, can be the same as you would use for the `SortedSet` as @Cuga suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a [TreeMultimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html) from the Google Guava libraries.

This will let your store your data as:

Score -> [Object, Object, Object]

This makes it easy to look up all the objects with a particular score. Some things that you can't do, though:

- Look up the score for a particular Object (you could use a regular Map for that in addition to the MultiMap)
- Atomically increment and decrement the score (you would need to remove the object from the score that it is currently assigned to and put it into its new score.)

Comment: I have thought about that, but would like to stay within core Java if possible.

Comment: You can create the equivalent of a TreeMultimap in core Java by just storing Lists as a your values in a regular TreeMap, it's just slightly more boilerplate. The keys being the score and the values being the objects.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a priority queue. Java's not my primary language, but it looks like the JDK already implements one in java.util.PriorityQueue. You may have to implement your own custom comparator object.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

In order to cycle through the priority queue in the appropriate order, just call poll() in a loop until poll() returns null.